# Alfresco's activiti add html file element in form

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I want to add a file upload html element in my process definition's start even in form.

```
<startEvent id="start" name="Start">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:formProperty id="name" name="Name"
                type="string" required="true" />
            <activiti:formProperty id="emailAddress" name="Email Address"
                type="string" required="true" />
            <activiti:formProperty id="income" name="Income"
                type="long" required="true" />
            <activiti:formProperty id="loanAmount" name="Loan Amount"
                type="long" required="true" />
        </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
```

I want to add a file uploader at the end to take file from user and process it further. I tried using file data type but of no use. Please guide as to how can I add a file element here.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify whether you are running Activiti embedded within Alfresco or separately from Alfresco.

Comment: I have ran this particular process from Activiti Explorer webapp.

Comment: Ok I was able to add textarea using FormType and Property Renderer, but not able to judge what to use for 'File Upload'.

Answer (score 0):

Append this for an upload field:

```
<activiti:formProperty id="attachfile" name="Atatch File"
                type="upload" required="true" />
```